# Combine OpenCV and FFMEG for faster video processing

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, ffmpeg

I am trying to process a video. To make it faster I would like to read it with ffmpeg and then sending the frame to cv2 for processing.

This is what I have done:

```
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import numpy as np

input_file = 'testvideo.mp4'


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_file)
ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, ch = frame.shape

ffmpeg = "C:\\Users\\totyped\\Downloads\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"
dimension = '{}x{}'.format(width, height)
f_format = 'bgr24' # remember OpenCV uses bgr format
fps = str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

command = [ffmpeg,
        '-i', input_file,
            '-r', fps,                  # FPS
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',        # opencv requires bgr24 pixel format.
            '-vcodec', 'mp4',
            '-an','-sn',                # disable audio processing
            '-f', 'image2pipe', '-']    

pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=10)

while True:
    frame =  pipe.stdout.read()
    image =  np.frombuffer(frame, dtype='uint8')        # convert read bytes to np


    cv2.imshow('Video', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
proc.stdin.close()
proc.stderr.close()
proc.wait()
```

I keep getting the same error:

> error: OpenCV(4.0.0)
>   C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:350:
>   error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in
>   function 'cv::imshow'

This is because something is wrong with the way that I retrieve the video.

Code was partially inspired from:
https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/b4jxdb/how_could_i_interface_ffmpeg_with_opencv_in/

EDIT:

```
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import numpy as np

input_file = 'testvideo.mp4'


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(input_file)
ret, frame = cap.read()
height, width, ch = frame.shape

ffmpeg = "C:\\Users\\totyped\\Downloads\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"
dimension = '{}x{}'.format(width, height)
f_format = 'bgr24' # remember OpenCV uses bgr format
fps = str(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

command = [ffmpeg,
        '-i', input_file,
            '-r', fps,                  # FPS
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',        # opencv requires bgr24 pixel format.
            '-vcodec', 'mp4',
            '-an','-sn',                # disable audio processing
            '-f', 'image2pipe', '-']    

pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=64000000)

while True:
    frame =  pipe.stdout.read(height*width*3)
    print(frame)
    image =  np.frombuffer(frame, dtype='uint8')        # convert read bytes to np


    cv2.imshow('Video', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

Comment: How will you get a frame of RGB video in a 10 byte buffer?

Comment: @MarkSetchell Actually not sure :/, what would you recommend to put there?

Comment: It would depend on several things... how much memory I had to spare, what the framesize is, what latency was acceptable. I would probably start testing around 64kB. Then I would try and read a whole frame because I would know how many bytes I was expecting.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I changed the buffer but still no image :(

Comment: @MarkSetchell The only thing I got was b''

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the premise on which your question is based. Why do you think `ffmpeg` will read your video from disk faster than OpenCV can? And why do you want it faster when you are only viewing it anyway?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am not viewing it. This code is just for demonstration purposes. I am actually processing it. The problem that I am facing with opencv, is that the longer I process the video, the slower it becomes. I have no clue why, so I was thinking of switching to ffmpeg.

Comment: Make the buffer much bigger. Set up a variable before you read each frame with `bytesremaining = w * h * 3` then go into a loop trying to read that many bytes. Decrement the variable by however many bytes you receive and move along a pointer to your buffer so that the next few bytes are appended at the right place.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I don't quite understand the loop, but I have implemented all your other suggestions. Please have a look at the updated question. Unfortunately, it still fails.

Comment: You appear to have made the buffer 64MB rather than 64kB. I have no idea what your width and height are, nor what you mean by *"It still fails"*. How does it fail? Is there an error? Do you get some bytes or none? Does it fail immediately or after a few minutes?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this - although I think you may be barking up the wrong tree by using `ffmpeg` because that's all that OpenCV uses under the covers. If you want more performance, maybe look more at multiprocessing - but this depends on the type of processing you are doing, which you haven't discussed or shown:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import numpy as np
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import numpy as np

ffmpeg = "ffmpeg"
input_file='test.mp4'
height, width = 480, 640
command = [ffmpeg,
            '-i', input_file,
            '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
            '-codec', 'rawvideo',
            '-an',
            '-sn',
            '-f', 'image2pipe', '-']   

pipe = sp.Popen(command, stdout = sp.PIPE, bufsize=65536)

frameCount=0
while True:
    nbytes = height*width*3
    print(f"Frame: {frameCount} - Trying to read {nbytes} bytes")
    frame =  pipe.stdout.read(nbytes)
    bytesRead = len(frame)
    print(f"Read {bytesRead} bytes")
    if bytesRead==0:
        break
    image =  np.frombuffer(frame, dtype='uint8')        # convert read bytes to np
    image = image.reshape((480,640,3))

    cv2.imshow('Video', image)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
    frameCount += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this some time ago. It also includes starting multiple streams with it. I have not tested this method for all stream types or file types. But I did for RTSP-UDP streams.

```
import numpy
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
import cv2

class ffmpeg_videocapture:
    def __init__(self, stream, width=640, height=360, scale=1, fps=15):
        self.command = 'ffmpeg -rtsp_transport udp -i {i} -pix_fmt bgr24 -s {w}x{h} -vcodec rawvideo ' \
                       '-an -sn -r {fps} -f image2pipe pipe:1'

        self.stream = stream
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.scale = scale
        self.fps = fps

        self.errors = []
        self.start()

    def start(self):
        width = int(self.width * self.scale)
        height = int(self.height * self.scale)
        command = self.command.format(i=self.stream, w=width, h=height, fps=self.fps)
        self.capture = Popen(command.split(' '), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, bufsize=10 ** 8)

    def read(self):
        width = int(self.width * self.scale)
        height = int(self.height * self.scale)
        raw_image = self.capture.stdout.read(width * height * 3)

        frame = numpy.fromstring(raw_image, dtype='uint8')
        frame = frame.reshape((height, width, 3))

        self.capture.stdout.flush()

        return frame is not None, frame

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.capture.terminate()


def single_camera(rtsp_stream):
    cap = ffmpeg_videocapture(rtsp_stream)
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rtsp_stream_list = [
        "rtsp_stream_1",
        "rtsp_stream_2",
        "etc...",
    ]

    for rtsp_stream in rtsp_stream_list:
        t = Process(target=single_camera, args=rtsp_stream)
        t.start()
```

I hope this will help you.