# Thermal Camera Not Working in Python3 OpenCV | MacOS

Tags: python, macos, opencv, avfoundation

I am getting error while trying to access thermal camera via OpenCV. The default camera works fine. Also, I am able to see thermal image via PhotoBooth.

ffmpg works as well:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "1" -target pal-vcd ./test.mpg
```

**ERROR:** [ERROR:0@0.108] global cap.cpp:323 open VIDEOIO(AVFOUNDATION): raised unknown C++ exception!

**Details**

- MacBook Pro 2023
- MacOs Version: Sonoma 14.1
- Python Version: 3.9.6
- OpenCV Version:  4.8.1
- Thermal Camera: ACEGMET TI256I (Connected via USB C port)

**Code**

```py
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print('Cannot open camera')
    exit()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print('Error reading frame. Exiting ...')
        break
    cv2.imshow('Webcam Frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Try the `ffmpeg` section of my answer here to see if you can find what resolutions and framerates your camera supports https://stackoverflow.com/a/74325989/2836621 You can install it with **homebrew** using `brew install ffmpeg`. You may also be able to capture video that way and if you can, we can pump that into **OpenCV**. Please click [edit] and add any new findings into your question where they can be formatted correctly, rather than as comments.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to capture video into the file with the following way. Here I am trying to get the stream real-time using OpenCV.

`ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "1" -target pal-vcd ./test.mpg`

Comment: Ok, so now you can read the camera, you should be able to pipe that into **OpenCV**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476274/2836621