# Python detecting color on MacOS screen

Tags: python, macos, colors, detection

I'm trying to make a python script that can work as an reaction time bot. Like I want to dected a color of a pixel on my screen as fast as possible, then click on it. But since i'm on a mac, I can't use windows packages. I trying to make something like this:

```
import os

pixel = (0, 0) #the coordinates of the pixel I am observing
green = (0, 0, 0) #the rgb values of green

while True:
    if os.get_pixel_rgb_color(pixel) == green:
        os.click(pixel)
```

but since packages like pyautogui (as far as I know) requires to take a screenshot in order to get rgb values. But these stuff take way more time and since I'm trying to make a reaction time bot, it would be too slow.

Comment: I can't tell from your question if a) you want to detect if a given pixel, say the one at (10,10) is green, or b) you want to detect if there is a green pixel anywhere on your screen. I also can't tell if you want to click on the green pixel if it appears, or if you want to actually click a button somewhere else.

Comment: I also imagine it is hard to see a specific pixel, so are you  actually looking for a green area rather than a pixel?

Comment: I want to detect the color of a single pixel on the screen. And it's also ok to detect a small area if it's really easier.

Comment: The fastest way I know of examining the screen on a Mac is with `ffmpeg`, see answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59089102/2836621  And a similar idea here, but using an `ffmpeg` subprocess from within Python to read the screen https://stackoverflow.com/a/58476274/2836621

Comment: I would try to insert a *"crop"* filter within `ffmpeg` to reduce to a minimum the amount of data flowing from `ffmpeg` into your Python process rather than needlessly passing the entire screen from `ffmpeg` to Python and then throwing 99% of it away.